# How to split a String delimited by space in groovy

Tags: string, groovy

I am trying to separate my String using spaces and extract the second text of the String value.

Here is my code -

```
String title = 'testing abcdefgh.abc.cde.fgh test testing issue'
String[] test = title.split(" ");
String[] newTest = test[1];
println newTest
```

Here is the output i am getting - [a, b, c, d, ., a, b, c, ., c, d, e, ., f, g, h]

NOw the output i am looking for is abcd.abc.cde.fgh, but i am getting [a, b, c, d, ., a, b, c, ., c, d, e, ., f, g, h]

I have used ("\s+"), ("\s"), just a space inside brackets, single and double quotes enclosing a space, nothing works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because here

```
String[] newTest = test[1]
```

You tell groovy to stick the string you want into a string array

So groovy tries to do what you say, and splits the characters out into separate strings

What you want is just a string, not a string array. Try

```
String newTest = test[1]
```

Instead

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in Java you have to escape a backslash in a String literal. So while the pattern you want is `\s+`, you have to put this in Java as `"\\s+"`